# How to assign JavasScript variable value to PHP variable in JavaScript function

Tags: mysql

How to assign value to Javascript variable value to PHP so that I can use that to value to store in MySQL database using PHP.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var countChecked = function(thiss) {
  var n = $( "input:checked" ).length;
 how to assign n to $temp?

<?php 
//$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ") or die("Couldn't connect to server!");
//$db=mysqli_select_db("site",$con) or die("Couldn't select database!");
//$query="INSERT INTO temp(value) VALUES ('$temp')";
?>


};
countChecked(thiss);
</script>
<body>
<h2>Price Range</h2>
    <div id="pricelabel" style="font-size: 15px; color:#696763 ;margin-left:1cm">
    <input id="price" type="checkbox" name="price" onclick="countChecked(1000)" value="500">0-500</input><br>
    <input id="price"type="checkbox" name="price" onclick="countChecked(1000)" value="1000">501-1000</input><br>
    <input id="price"type="checkbox" name="price" onclick="countChecked(1500)"value="1500">1001-1500</input><br>
    <input id="price" type="checkbox" name="price" onclick="countChecked(2000)"  value="2000">1501-2000</input><br>
                            <input id="price" type="checkbox" name="price" onclick="countChecked(2001)" value="<2000"><2001</input><br>
                            <div id="p"></div>
                            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should realize that the javascript code and the php code run at completely different times. You cant simply let them exchange variables without using ajax

Comment: If you want to transfer data from Javascript to PHP you will need an Ajax call to submit data to PHP where you can store server side variables and session variables using the target PHP file. If you want PHP data in Jacascript you can call a similar AJAX call to load a PHP file which can output javascript to be executed on the page changing client side data and variables.